# SQL query to count question marks in comment field?

Tags: mysql

Wanted to ask if anyone can help me with (code or commands to use) an sql query to count how many times the question mark character appears in table *exp_comments*, field *comment*?

Thanks!
Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a total of all occurrences across all comments:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(comment) - LENGTH(REPLACE(comment, '?', ''))) AS occurrences FROM exp_comments
```

To get the count for each comment in a query result:

```
SELECT LENGTH(comment) - LENGTH(REPLACE(comment, '?', '')) AS occurrences FROM exp_comments
```

(MySQL doesn't have a specific function for this, but I found this clever technique - which takes the field's character count and subtracts its count with all of your target character removed - [here](http://pisceansheart.wordpress.com/2008/04/15/count-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string-using-mysql/).)